# Difference between xs and xcs in XML schema file?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, xsd, xml-namespaces

For some reason Visual Studio wants me to do

```
<xcs:element ...>
</xcs:element>
```

rather than

```
<xs:element ...?
</xs:element>
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XML, element names are defined by the developer. This often results in a conflict when trying to mix XML documents from different XML applications.

Name conflicts in XML can easily be avoided using a name prefix.

But When using prefixes in XML, a so-called namespace for the prefix must be defined.

The main common is **xs** but you can define the profix you prefer.

An example from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/):

```
<root>

<h:table xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>Apples</h:td>
    <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:table>

<f:table xmlns:f="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
  <f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name>
  <f:width>80</f:width>
  <f:length>120</f:length>
</f:table>

</root>
```

For more explanations see [XML Namespaces](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer is that it depends on what `xs` and `xsc` are defined as. They are aliases for the actual namespaces used. If they are defined to be the same namespace, then the two examples are identical.